# unknown type name "Engine"

Tags: c, types

I am getting an error:

```
engine/renderer/render.h:8:19: error: unknown type name ‘Engine’
    8 | void initRenderer(Engine* engine);
      |                   ^~~~~~
```

Even though I have defined the type Engine and included it in the render.h file

app.h:

```c
#pragma once

#include <defines.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <containers/vector.h>

typedef struct Engine {
    uint16 w;
    uint16 h;
    GLFWwindow* window;
    int backend;
    Vector entities;
    char* name;

    void* (*Update)();
    void* (*onStart)();
} Engine;
```

render.h:

```c
#pragma once

#include <defines.h>

#include <renderer/backend/vulkan.h>
#include <app.h>

void initRenderer(Engine* engine);
```

I have included `<app.h>` in the include directory of the project with `-I` and it works in all other files

Comment: I believe you want `#include "app.h"`.

Comment: The files are not in the same directory and I included the directory "app.h" is in with ```-I```, I did try doing ```#include "../core/app.h"``` but it still gave the same errors

Comment: The point of `-I` is so you can do `#include "app.h"` without the path.  `#include <app.h>` is different, and is going to search through your system paths instead.

Comment: You could try getting the compiler to output the pre-processed code and see if that helps. For gcc, it is "-E". For others, you'd have to do some research.

Comment: @Jason I tried that before and it still didn't work. Though I didn't know about the ```<>``` thing since it seemed to work for me before

Comment: @pmacfarlane I tried that and it seems the declaration for the Engine struct is defined in the same way in the output file.

Comment: Well we know nothing about the .c file you are compiling. Presumably one of the .c files is failing to build. Can you place a #error "hello" statement in app.h right after Engine gets defined, then try to compile that .c file? Do you see the "hello" error?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I did that and yes, I do. I don't think the problem is with the definition of Engine since I used it in other places and this is the only place where it gives me a problem

Comment: Well this is all very unlikely. Can you chop it down to something small that we can try to compile? Maybe just your .c file and app.h. And your makefile/CMake/whatever.

Comment: @pmacfarlane made a github repo that produces the same errors: https://github.com/sako-is/question-demo/